# Is this a good way to use Try catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm new to handling errors and am not sure how to do it, basically, in a speicific request `err.code === 11000` is not actually an error, but expected behaviour. I want to output it but not like another error and I want the code to continue running. I don't think it looks nice.

```
(async () =>{
  let client;
  try {
    client = await MongoClient;
    let sales = await call(),
        collection = client.db("scraper").collection("sold");
        try {
          stored = await collection.insertMany(sales.sold, {ordered: false});
          console.log({completed: stored.result.n})
        }catch(err){
          if(err.code === 11000){log({completed: err.result.nInserted, duplicates: err.result.result.writeErrors.length})}
          else{log( {err} )}
        }
    //console.log(sales)
  } catch(err) {
    log(err)
  }
  client.close();
})()
```

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226).

Comment: Did the code work as intended? So you just ask if you did it in a good and standard way? Are thoses assumption corrects?

Comment: @Calak yes, the output is as desired, or well, I'm not really sure what to do with them, but I need to handle the errors or it won't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that the error code is not 11000 I would re-throw the error in the inner try. That way you do not repeat, possibly complex error logic or possibly execute code that you do not want to. i.e. instead of

```
try {
  try {
    // code
  } catch(err) {
    if (err.code === 11000) { 
      log({completed: err.result.nInserted, duplicates: err.result.result.writeErrors.length})
    } else { 
      log('an error occurred', {err} )
    }
  }
  //code that shouldn't execute when an error occurs
} catch(err) {
  log('an error occurred', {err} )
}
```

something like

```
try {
  try {
    // code
  } catch(err1) {
    if (err1.code !== 11000) {
      throw err1;
    } 
    log({completed: err1.result.nInserted, duplicates: err1.result.result.writeErrors.length})
  }
  //code that shouldn't execute when an error occurs
} catch(err2) {
  log('an error occurred', {err2} )
}
```

I also suggest using different variable names in different exception handlers. Some spaces between parentheses and curly brackets would also make your code more readable.